# Using CMAKE to generate Visual Studio 2019 ARM project file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, raspberry-pi, arm

I am using Visual Studio 2019 to cross platform build on Raspberry Pi. Works very well.
Now I wonder if I can use cmake to generate project files for me to integrate libraries like restbed or cpprestsdk.
What I am struggling with is that

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A ARM ../"
```

produces

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
```

What is the best way to get the libraries ready for me to integrate them in my Raspberry Visual Studio project?

Comment: I have never used CMake to build for an ARM platform. But I think it is possible that CMake looks on your machine for an ARM compiler and does not find one.

Comment: Agree. But what is the best way? Visual Studio 2019 is installed with the Linux ARM compilers. How do I need to configure CMake to build the projects for me?

Comment: You could manually set the environment variables ```CC``` and ```CXX``` to point to the executables of the ARM C and C++ compilers. Another alternative would be a toolchain file: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html

Comment: Make sure you are using the Visual Studio ARM for Cross Tools Command Prompt.